# PostgreSQL NOTIFY queue empty after LISTEN

Tags: postgresql, ipc, postgresql-9.5

I am new at PostgreSQL `LISTEN`/`NOTIFY` features. After the `LISTEN` command,

```
LISTEN mychannel;
```

We can `NOTIFY` messages to the channel.

```
NOTIFY mychannel 'Hello';
```

1. This `NOTIFY` messages is saved somewhere in database. Where? Can I see messages using select query from a table?
2. If I `NOTIFY` 3 or 5 messages, these are saved on queue. I run the `LISTEN` command using a programming language, all messages handled and messages removed from queue. If my client crashed, all messages will be lost. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that you misunderstand `LISTEN`. It is for asynchronous communication between *active* sessions. The messages are not stored anywhere.

If you want a persistent dara structure for communication between two parts of your application, you are probably looking for a *queue*.

Since queues are notoriously hard to implement in relational databases, I suggest that you use one of the existing third party implementations for PostgreSQL.

`LISTEN` / `NOTIFY` can be part of such a queue implementation to make it unnecessary for the recipients to poll the queue regularly.